# How to specify device when running an iOS React Native project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, react-native, webstorm

I have a basic React Native project setup in IntelliJ IDEA IDE. When I hit "Run" it runs on iOS Simulator without asking which device to run on, but I want to run it on a physical device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did this by adding a device argument in the run configuration.

Goto -> Run(on toolbar) -> Select the project -> add "--device [DEVICE_NAME]" to the  "Run arguments" field, click apply/Ok and you're good to go.

[screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQfaA.png)

PS : To know or change the name of your physical iPhone, on the iPhone goto Settings -> General -> About, and the name should be there.

Also, if you want to check if your mac can see your plugged in device, run "instruments -s devices" in the terminal to see all devices connected including simulators.